Adding a Context Menu to a dataGridView
VS2019 .NET 4.62
I couldn't figure out all of the examples and finally horsed my way to a working solution.
But, surely, there is a better way to do this?
When I use a delegate in other modes I am able to add parameters, here I couldn't?
Ex:
btnAddFrom.Click += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e) { add_TransAcctName(sender, e, lstFrom, txtFrom); };
btnAddTo.Click += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e) { add_TransAcctName(sender, e, lstTo, txtTo); };

So, I've got to wonder what am I missing where I can't append rowIndex and ColIndex and not have to use a global variable.
// Required until I learn how to pass within the delegate
int rowIndex = 0;
int colIndex = 0;
private void dgvStatement_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{   // ####### A Context menu Strip does not easily allow for recognizing Row and Column #######
    rowIndex = dgvStatement.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex; 
    colIndex = dgvStatement.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).ColumnIndex;
    // Test for Right Mouse Click
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)     
    {
        // Create a Context menu cm
        ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
        // Give it a name
        cm.Name = "Data Grid View Opions";
        // Create a Named Menu Item, reqired for creating the delegate  
        MenuItem m0 = new MenuItem("Move Columns Right");    
        //Add to the Context menu list
        cm.MenuItems.Add(m0 = new MenuItem("Move Columns Right"));  
        // Add the Delegate object sender & EventArgs e are included by default
        m0.Click += new EventHandler(dgv_MoveColRight); 
        // Show the context menu
        cm.Show(dgvStatement, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    }
}

// Note: No Click in function Name
private void dgv_MoveColRight(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    showMe.Comment = "dgv_MoveColRight";
    showMe.Comment = e.ToString();
    showMe.Comment = sender.ToString();
    showMe.Comment = "Row: " + rowIndex;
    showMe.Comment = "Col: " + colIndex;
}

showMe.Comment is a troubleshooting form with a list to display various "stuff" while learning.
